# MAGENTO - Static page content not output

Tags: magento, static

Im having a big issue with static pages on my Magento install.

I have several stores setup.  eg, store1, store2, store3...
Store 1, static pages seem to work fine.
Store 2 + 3, the element 'col-main' is always empty.

Ive debugged the page controller.  The page content is in the database, but when it renders the layout for the page, the content is not added to the output!

I am unsure what else i can do...can anyone shed any light on why this may be happening?

many thanks
Shaun

Comment: Seems to add something in their. The element is empty, but has an invisible line break! when i delete the space added in the element on output, the whole page content shifts up.
Strange...as whitespace shouldnt cause a line break.....a BR tag is needed for that....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your page content coming from CMS pages? I'd suggest making sure the "scope" of the pages is set correctly to allow them to show across your stores. You can do this by going to CMS -> Pages, select one of your pages and on the "Page Information" tab make sure the "Store View" multi-select has all the applicable store views selected.

If your page still doesn't show after a refresh, drop a reply here and I'll help you debug it further.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.
I have already done this. Ive tried allocating to specific stores...AND added as global scope. Also tried adding to 'main website store view'.....nothing!  :(

Comment: Okay not to worry. Can you let me know what the URL key of the page is and send me links to the working page on Store1 and the non-functional counterpart on one of your other stores? If you want to do this privately you're welcome to email me at stackoverflow@wildworx.co.uk and I'll try to assist you futher. Once we determine the problem we can post it back here for the benefit of the community.

Comment: solved!  Thanks to the help of wildworx!

the site i was having problems with, was using its own default folder (not inheriting the usual magento default folder). The cms.xml file didnt have all the required structure within it....just store-specific change information, thinking it was inherting from the default.

Adding the xml from the USUAL DEFAULT cms.xml file, into the cms.xml file being used...solved the issue.

Comment: the cms.xml thing worked for me - put an almost blank - replaced this with default and it now works!